# strange css hover effect when hovering html element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flex in CSS to create a grid of thumbnails.  This grid looks fine and displays as i want.  I have since tried to add a hover effect to the image section which triggers a CSS hover event and changes the opacity of a div that's hidden.

The strange thing is if i have 10 flex boxes all on one row the hover event triggers correctly on each separate flex item.  However as soon as a flex item wraps to the next line the hover event does not work correctly and applies the event to random elements.

I've posted the code at JSFiddle, it does not contain images or icons but the effect is still the same. https://jsfiddle.net/nathanrhys/vf5z53sc/

For completeness here is the `<li>` html (obviously there are more than one item in real life)

```
<ul class="flex-container">
<li class="flex-item">
      <div class="thumbnail-container">
            <div class="roll">
                 <i class="captionicons fa fa-expand fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img class="image-item" src="Images/IMAGE (474).JPG" />
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail-title">DSC_00233.jpg</div>
            <div class="thumbnail-icons">
            <section>
                 <div class="thumbleft"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp&nbsp <b>620</b></div>
                 <div class="thumbright"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </section>
            </div>
      </div></li></ul>
```

And the CSS for these items

```
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    color: white;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 3px;
    height: 160px;
}

.image-item {
    max-width: calc(200px - 3px);
    max-height: calc(160px - 3px);
}

 .roll:hover  {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

}

.roll {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: 166px;
    top:19px;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I'm new to this so please help me find my mistake, I've tried moving the hover to the top most div flex-item but this still causes the same issue.

Comment: sorry my bad! https://jsfiddle.net/nathanrhys/vf5z53sc/

Comment: Since you set position absolute in the .roll class, when the image container wraps to a new row, the div with the roll class remains in the first row, so you are not really hovering on it

Comment: your markup is a mess , i suggest you if you wanna use replace it with something cleaner

Comment: @CameronA can you suggest what should be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Denis i realised i hadn't set the position in the `.image-container` to relative.  By adding

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

to `.image-container` the hover works as expected.

I have updated this at JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/nathanrhys/a7tbgwzr/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works. Instead of having a div with class roll that has initial opacity of 0 that then changes to 0.6 on hover, you can put a black background on the image container. Then when you hover over the image you reduce it's opacity and you will get essentially the same effect. Add this to your CSS:

```
.image-item:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Take a look at this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf5z53sc/2/)

Comment: that's great the only thing is how do i then contain an icon in this hover event.  Essentially when a user hovers over the image i want to place 2 buttons for them to click?  There was  an icon in my previous example but wasn't showing because it was font awesome, thanks nathan